# Renaming .jpg files in subdirectories without changing the creation date (on a MAC)

Tags: macos, command-line, batch-rename

I have a bunch of JPEG files with exactly the same name (i.e. "orig.jpg") each in a seperate subdirectory. Each subdirectory has a unique name (e.g. xplmz3nc5n, tyrn5m6ktv, etc...).

I want to rename the jpegs based on their creation date/time (e.g. 20120629_142536.jpg, etc..).

I was able to use photoshop to batch rename each file with a unique identifier. The key feature that allowed this was photoshop's ability to "include all subdirectories" in a batch process. I was hoping to be able then use exiftool to rename the files to include the creation date (for easy cataloging). Unfortunately, the photoshop batch rename process rewrites the creation date of the file to today's date...

Any suggestions on a way to batch rename the files in a series of subdirectories using, say, terminal commands?

**EDIT**

The answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/610367/copy-files-and-rename-them-by-creation-date) and got the following result in Terminal

```
cd ~/foo
for dir in *; do 
    t=`stat -c %y "$dir" | awk '{print $1"-"$2}' | 
       cut -d ":" -f 1,2 | sed 's/://'`
    mv "$dir" "$t"_"$dir";
done
```

and got

> stat: illegal option -- c usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...] 
>   stat: illegal option -- c usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...] 
>   stat: illegal option -- c usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]

(i.e. I tried two different methods...).

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: "but won't work in Darwin.." Why do you say that? What did you try exactly, and what were the results?

Comment: I'm really at a loose end with this. Please post an answer if you know how this would be done. Thanks.

Comment: Graphic Converter (shareware, not free, but might have a free trial) has some GREAT rename options.  I use this ALL the time to manage my digital photos.  If you're not a programmer, I'd try to get a tool that does this for you.  (I *am* a programmer, and I still use "GC" for this kind of thing!)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility using the EXIF creation date would be (untested but should work):

- move all your files into the same directory, renaming them to a unique name (e.g. the name of the containing directory plus the `.jpg` suffix)

  ```
  cd ~/foo
  for i in */; do
    # moves the file (supposedly named orig.jpg) in current directory
    # renaming it to the name of the containing sub directory
    mv ${i}orig.jpg ./`basename $i`.jpg
    # removes the subdirectory, assuming it is now empty
    rmdir $i;
  done
  ```

  If the files are not always named the same way, but there is only a single file (with name ending in `.jpg`) in the subdirectory, you can of course replace the `mv` command with:

  ```
    mv ${i}*.jpg ./`basename $i`.jpg
  ```
- then rename them using `exiftool`:

  ```
  exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S.jpg "-filename<CreateDate" ~/foo
  ```

  This assumes that no files will have the same creation time down to the seconds level. If there is a risk of filename collision, you can use a variant that adds a suffix to the file name in case of a duplicate name:

  ```
  exiftool -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S%-c.jpg "-filename<CreateDate" ~/foo
  ```

More info about the renaming function of `exiftool` here: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html

Comment: I get the following error: `mv: rename ff76e77ec7438371b42fc5027ad00486//orig.jpg to ./.jpg: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Ah... didn't consider that directory names would end with /, was working on Linux but not necessarily on MacOS... updated with an improved version. I don't have a Mac around now to test, unfortunately.

Comment: btw did you check if `ff76e77ec7438371b42fc5027ad00486/orig.jpg` actually exists?

Comment: Yes, I checked. There appears to be a syntax issue with your new edited code. it tries to find `dirname/dirname.jpg` and says there is no such file. It might need someone with a mac to test properly. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Are you using bash as a shell?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OSX does not have the GNU tools but instead, it's core utilities are forks of the BSD versions. This means that many command line answers that you find for Linux won't apply. Either because the relevant options are missing or because they're different.

I don't have an OSX machine to test this on but based on the OSX man pages for [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) and [`date`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html), this should do what you need:

```
find . -name orig.jpg | 
    while read file; do
     echo mv "$file" "$(date -jf "$(stat -f '%m' "$file")" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)".jpg
    done
```

If your directory names can contain spaces or other strange characters, use this instead:

```
find . -name orig.jpg -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
     echo mv "$file" "$(date -jf "$(stat -f '%m' $file)" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)".jpg
    done
```

That will just print the commands that will be run. If they are correct, remove the `echo` and run it again to actually rename the files. As I said, I can't test this since I don't have access to an OSX machine so you might have to tweak it. Have a look at the man pages I linked to (or run `man stat` on your machine). I am not sure that OSX's `date` can deal with the output of `stat -f '%m'`, if not, let me know and I'll try and help.

#### Explanation

- `find . -name orig.jpg` : recursively find all files called `origin.jpg` in the current folder.
- `while read file; ... ; do` : this will save each of the file names found by `find` as `$file` and then run the next commands on each of them.
- `stat -f '%m' $file` : this should show the modification time of the file in a human-readable format.
- `$(date -jf "DATE" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` : print the date given by `DATE` as YYMMDD_HHMMSS. Since we are giving it the output of `stat -f '%m' $file`, that will print the date that the file was modified.
- `mv "$file" "$(date -jf "$(stat -f '%m' $file)" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)".jpg` : rename `$file` to the date returned by `date` and `.jpg`.

The equivalent command on Linux is:

```
find . -name orig.jpg | 
    while read file; do 
        echo mv "$file" "$(date -d "$(stat -c '%y' $file)" +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)".jpg
   done
```